# Timestamp in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have timestamp problem in Highcharts

Displays the date and time in java coding

Sorry for my bad English :/

The chart code:

```
    var options ={
      chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'line',

      },
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruits Amount'
        }
    },
       series: [{
       }]
    };
    $.getJSON('data.php', function(data){
       options.series[0].data = data;
       var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

The JSON data from data.php:

```
[
    [1531972144000,20.94],
    [1531972204000,20.94],
    [1531972264000,20.85],
    [1531972324000,20.94],
    [1531972384000,21.21],
    [1531972444000,20.94],
    [1531972504000,21.12],
    [1531972564000,21.21],
    [1531972624000,21.12],
    [1531972684000,21.38],
    [1531972749000,21.56],
    [1531972809000,21.29],
    [1531972869000,21.64],
    [1531972929000,21.29],
    [1531972989000,21.29],
    [1531973049000,21.21],
    [1531973109000,21.38],
    [1531973169000,21.29],
    [1531973229000,21.29],
    [1531973289000,20.94]
]
```

how to write data from the **database** instead of these values?

Comment: Please post your code in the text of the question, not as an external link. Links can break over time, making questions impossible to understand for people with similar problems in the future.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It would depend on your database format of the timestamp. There are many methods but they depend on your source data format.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the `xAxis.type` - [Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type) like this

```
xAxis:{
    type:'datetime'
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8o6rmLh/)

Comment: Thank you,

how to write data from the database instead of these values

it can not be done like this:


http://jsfiddle.net/f8qa3nx9/

Comment: No you can't directly use database data. You nedd to use like you did already `$.getJSON('data.php', function(data){
       options.series[0].data = data;
       var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });`

Comment: And how add this range selector: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

to this code: http://tws.4fan.cz/data/code.txt

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Just change the script link from `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` to `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>`

Comment: I have a problem again.

I do not want a certain number of records.

code: http://tws.4fan.cz/arduino/text.txt
Printscreen for understanding: http://tws.4fan.cz/arduino/png.png